# how to write new file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing a new file with the following code

```
const Image=req.body.Image;
const imageName = `frame_${Date.now()}.jpg`;
const imagePath = `../images/${imageName}`
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(Image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), 'base64');
fs.writeFile(imagePath, imageBuffer, (err) => {
    if (err) {
         console.error('Error saving image:', err);
    } else {
         console.log('Image saved:', imageName);
     }
});
```

The image path I am using is the image folder I have created for it .[image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KGJE.png)

is the file path wrong ?

but the file is not get created there and I am getting this output [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/583L5.png)

what I am doing incorrect in creating the file ?

I want to create the file from datURL and store it in DB for further operations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an absolute path using process.cwd()?

```
const imagePath = join(process.cwd(), 'images', imageName);
```

It's unclear where the root of your project is (where you are running node), that you need further directories before 'images'.

Comment: I want to convert the dataUrl to a file to upload it. Can u tell me how to write this file  ?

Comment: The error it's giving in your output is that it can't create the output file.  This may be because the path is wrong in relation to where your root is.  With the change I suggested, is it still failing?